# Pandas long to wide without losing timezone awareness

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, reshape

I'm trying to reshape a pandas dataframe from long to wide format and the timestamps lose the timezone.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
long = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    ind=[1,1,2, 2],
    events=['event1', 'event2', 'event1', 'event2'],
    time=[pd.Timestamp('2015-03-30 00:00:00', tz='UTC'),
         pd.Timestamp('2015-03-30 01:00:00', tz='UTC'),
         pd.Timestamp('2015-03-30 02:00:00', tz='UTC'),
         pd.Timestamp('2015-03-30 03:00:00', tz='UTC')]))
```

Then when looking at `long.time` I get a timezone-aware serie.

```
0   2015-03-30 00:00:00+00:00
1   2015-03-30 01:00:00+00:00
2   2015-03-30 02:00:00+00:00
3   2015-03-30 03:00:00+00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

and after reshaping like this

```
wide = long.set_index(['ind'] + ['events']).unstack(level=1).reset_index()
```

the timezone goes away. E.g. `wide.time.event1`

```
0   2015-03-30 00:00:00
1   2015-03-30 02:00:00
Name: event1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Is there another way of reshaping that does not lose the timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` is tracking the timezone.  When, you `unstack`, that reshaping must be happening in `numpy` which loses track.  This is proven by

```
df = pd.concat([long.time, pd.Series(long.time.values)],
               axis=1, keys=['pandas', 'numpy'])

df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes    

pandas    datetime64[ns, UTC]
numpy          datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

Work around is to recast each column as the dtype you care about

```
for c, col in wide.filter(like='time').iteritems():
    wide[c] = col.astype(long.time.dtype)

wide
```

[image]

Comment: @kael upated post